# How to slow down a video without slowing down the audio?

Tags: ffmpeg, handbrake

I have a security camera that records a 1 min video and compresses it to 40 seconds. The audio is ok. How do I slow down the video from 1.5x to 1.0x without altering the audio?

Comment: What is the video format of the files?

Comment: The audio would be out of sync. But maybe you don't want that but instead keep the pitch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Using a player to slow down a video without slowing down the audio

You can avoid having to re-encode by having your player slow down the video. Example using `mpv`:

```
mpv --vf=setpts=1.5*PTS input.mp4
```

#### Using ffmpeg to slow down a video without slowing down the audio

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "setpts=1.5*PTS" -c:a copy output.mp4
```

- This re-encodes the video.
- No need to separate audio and video beforehand.
- The audio is [stream copied](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy), so audio will not be altered.

#### More info

- [setpts filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setpts_002c-asetpts)
- [FFmpeg Wiki: Speeding up / slowing down video](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video)

Answer (score 0):

To slow down only the video, what you need to do is to first separate
the audio and video components. Then you can slow down the video,
and finally combine the two again. The video will then end in silence,
unless you dub in some other audio.

Here is how to do that with the free version of
[Easy Video Maker](https://www.easymakevideo.com/):

- Drag and drop the source video into the media area
- Right-click the video and select *Add Selected To > Video Line*
- Right-click again the video and select *Add Selected To > Audio 0 Line*
- Right-click the video that is in Video Line, and select
  *Audio > Disable Audio” to mute the video
  (the original audio is still in Audio Line)
- Right-click the video in Video Line again, and select
  *Playback speed rate* to slow down the video
- At last, click the lower-right *Export* button to output a new media file
  with slow playback video and normal speed audio.

Answer (score 0):

With ffmpeg, you can separate the audio and video, slow down the video and then join the audio to the slow video.

a. Separate video and audio -

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -c:v copy -an onlyVideo.mp4
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vn -acodec copy onlyAudio.wav
```

b. Slow down video - https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video

`ffmpeg -i onlyVideo.mp4 -filter:v "setpts=1.5*PTS" slow.mp4`

c. Join audio to slow video

`ffmpeg -i slow.mp4 -i onlyAudio.wav -c:v copy -c:a aac output.mp4`